# React WebPack - Send My Work to online Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a online server where i put my works and portfolio and stuff , i have made a simple app in react and i want to run it in my server, but im getting the error

http://hseleiro.pt/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

What im i doing wrong ? i dont know if im making the correct steps to show my react app in a online server, could some one help me ?

I have tried to change my pat on my Webpack.config.js but with no sucess.

Index.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.hseleiro.pt/ReduxSimpleStarter/style/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container"></div>
</body>
 <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

WebPack.Config.Js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
'./src/index.js'
],
output: {
  path: __dirname,
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
  loaders: [{
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
  }
 }]
 },
 resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
 },
devServer: {
 historyApiFallback: true,
  contentBase: './'
}
};
```

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to expose the main `index.html` file you are using for your site and the bundle file on your server. The index file should contain a script tag, like this `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` that references the source bundle you created with Webpack. When the site loads the bundle, your react app should start running.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i have the script tag and its not working :( i already tried to change the tag to !!  <script src="http://hseleiro.pt/ReduxSimpleStarter/bundle.js"></script> and its not working :( !! Thanks for the help